# Is it legal to use char overflow in C++ code

Tags: c++

Good day, colleagues!

I need to obtain cyclic series on successive numbers from 0 to 255. Is it legal to use unsigned char overflow like this:

```
unsigned char test_char = 0;

while (true) {
    std::cout << test_char++ << " ";
}
```

Or will be more safely to use this code:

```
int test_int = 0;

while (true) {
    std::cout << test_int++ % 256 << " ";
}
```

Of course, in real code there will be reasonable condition instead of while (true).

Comment: you need to worry about integer wrap around with your second case.

Comment: Wrap around is solved by `unsigned int`. And `unsigned int`'s period is an (unspecified) multiple of 256, so it's perfectly safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though sizeof(char) will always be 1, it is not necessary that a char will be exactly 8 bits. (I am guessing unsigned char will be similar).

So of the two, if given a choice, I would prefer the latter as the former might not even be correct.

btw, You probably intended unsigned int instead of int for the latter? Modulus with negative numbers could get tricky (after the int overflows, as Jimmy noted). If I recollect correctly, I believe it is compiler dependent.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Of course, I meant unsigned int in latter.

Answer (score 8):

3.9.1/4 "Unsigned integers, declared unsigned, shall obey the laws of arithmetic modulo 2n where n is the number of bits in the value representation of that particular size of integer"

"This implies that unsigned arithmetic does not overflow because a result that cannot be represented by the resulting unsigned integer type is reduced modulo the number that is one greater than the largest value that can be represented by the resulting unsigned integer type"

So, yes it is legal. And the second form is preferred, since it's more readable.

Comment: But the number of bits isn't guaranteed to be 8.

Comment: Note however, that char is **not** guaranteed to be 8 bits in size. It *is* guaranteed to be one *byte* in size, but there exist architectures where 1 byte is not 8 bits in size, and hence char will not overflow after 255. Not that you're actually likely to have to use such a platform... :) **EDIT** just beat me @Potatoswatter!

Comment: No, but still the arithmetic he uses is legal. If he works on a system with larger char's he'll notice quickly enough (and it won't matter if he uses the readable version)

Answer (score 1):

unsigned char, like all other unsigned integral types, follows modulo 2<sup>n</sup> arithmetic, so basically both your methods are equivalent. Use the first

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as unsigned overflow, per 3.9.1/4 as quoted by Erik. However, as Moron says, it is possible that the modulus of the `unsigned char` number system is greater than 256.

Note that your expression does not store the result of `% 256` back to `test_int`. The safe way to do this is

```
test_int = ( test_int + 1 ) % 256;
std::cout << test_int << " ";
```

Answer (score 0):

the output of the 2 samples is completely different.
the first one will print characters (a b c d e f g h ...)
the second one will print integers (0 1 2 3 4 ... 255 0 ...)
anyway it depends if you have a a control for overflowexception (.NET) otherwise in old C++ it the value is always valid and goes from 0 to 255